# JBoss HTTPS connection dies after a while

Tags: jboss

I have a JBoss 7.2 app server and I start the server, I am able to connect to both the http and https ports but after a while running the server, I am not able to connect to the https port anymore but the http port still works so the server is still running. I tail the logs when I try to connect to the https port but nothing shows up and when I do a netstat on the https port, the port is still listening. Has anyone had this type of issue before?

### JBoss Standalone.xml configuration

```
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="${jboss.home.dir}/standalone/configuration/XXXXX.keystore" keystore-password="XXXXXXXXX" alias="1"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>






    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" enable-http2="true" ssl-session-cache-size="500" ssl-session-timeout="1800"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %{i,Referer} %{i,User-Agent} %S %T %{i,X-Forwarded-For}" prefix="access_log_"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: How are you starting jboss server?

Comment: So I have a bamboo script that does my deploy and start up and I have the server configuration in a repository branch. Each time I do a deploy, I blow out the server and reinstall it then start against the configuration on the repository using the command:   


${serverPath}/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=${configFile} -b=${hostBindIP} -bmanagement=${hostManagementBindIP} -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=${serverPortOffset} -Djboss.server.log.dir=${loggingDirectory} --git-repo=${configGitRepository} --git-branch=${configGitBranch} >${loggingDirectory}/nohup.out 2>&1 &

Comment: Are you getting jboss shutting down logs in your jboss server logs?

Comment: And what do you mean by https connection dies? Are you not able to access application using https protocols/listners?

Comment: I have logs for when I shutdown the jboss server. when I use the die, I meant I could not access the https protocools/listener. The server is still up cos I can use the http ports to access the jboss server but https just stops connecting. When I check the https ports on the host, it is still listening but for some reason, it is not receiving request again.